# Is it possible to make Java ME application applying phone cell tower location to get a fingerprint to the location

Tags: java, java-me, mobile

I know that it is quite difficult to know the location from the cell tower because we have to know the exact location of cell tower which is a BLACK BOX to network operator. My question is to get a fingerprint of a location. So , If I am at a certain location , I will store it as position X. Then I have been at this location again , then the phone will detect that the position is X .

Question :

1. Is this possible .
2. how about accuracy .
3. Can I do this Program to run on Java mobile application .
4. are there any recommendations to
   start with as I am very new to Java
   ME . I want to know which langauge
   to use , netbeans , eclipse or other
   , ....
5. Do you have any resource that will
   make life easier for me

Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1):

you can get current CellID by

```
Criteria cr= new Criteria();
cr.setHorizontalAccuracy(500);

// Get an instance of the provider
LocationProvider lp= LocationProvider.getInstance(cr);

// Request the location, setting a one-minute timeout
Location l = lp.getLocation(60);
Coordinates c = l.getQualifiedCoordinates();

if(c != null ) {
  // Use coordinate information
  double lat = c.getLatitude();
  double lon = c.getLongitude();
}
```

Using xellid you can get coordinated from [opencelid](http://www.opencellid.org) database accuracy may vary from 500 m to 20 km

Comment: Dear Nirma ,  Thanks so much . it seems wonderful . but i have a question , why the accuracy is 500 m . I find googlemaps accurate to a range of 10 meters only . Moreover , google maps uses the triangulation method . this means that the phone must get at least three cell tower ID , then it performs calculations . Is this possible to make the phone J2ME application gets all cellIds that the phone can connect to .

Comment: you can get only one cell id at one place

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/location/

Comment: IT looks great , but too compliucated . I hope you can give more clarification .   Thanks.